# MongoDb Logical Query Operators and Braces

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

What is the Rule with using Braces when nesting and using logical operators in mongoDB when running aggregation queries some queries work and others don't as shown below ?

> scenario 1 (works) :
>
> ```
>  $project:
>  {
>   $and: [ { $gt: [ "$qty", 100 ] }, { $lt: [ "$qty", 250 ] }]
>  }
> ```

---

> ```
> scenario 2 (works):
>
> $project:
> {
>  $and:[{"data":"Residential"},{"status":true}],                                                                                       
> }
> ```

---

> scenario 3 (works)
>
> ```
> $and:
> [
>  {
>   $and:[{"data":"Residential"},{"status":true}],                                                                                          
>   $and:[{"data":"Lobby"},{"status":true}],                                                                                                                            
>  }
> ]
> ```

---

> scenario 3 (would give a different result from scenario 2 result)
>
> ```
> $and:
> [
>   {
>     $and:[{"data":"Residential"},{"status":true}],    
>   },
>   {                                                                                       
>     $and:[{"data":"Lobby"},{"status":true}],                                                                                                                          
>   }
> ]
> ```

---

scenario 4 (works):

> ```
> $and:[
>   {
>     $or:[
>          {
>           $and:[
>                  {"data":"Kids"},
>                  {"status":true}
>                ]  
>          },
>         {                                         
>          $and:[                       
>                  {"data":"Adults"},
>                  {"status":true}                                                                                                  
>              ]                                        
>          }
>        ]
>       }                                                                                                                               
> ]
> ```

Scenario 4 would give a different result if i was to do :

> ```
> $and:[
> {                                          
>  $or:
>  [
>   {
>     $and:[{"data":"Kids"},{“status":true} ].                                        
>     $and:[{"data":"Adults"},{"status":true} ]                                   
>   }
>  ]
> }
> ],
> ```

Such details are not indicated in the documentation any where.

Answer (score 0):

So One thing i have realized is that nested braces with $and or $or can be treated as a separate step/stage depending on how we use them. This concept is called **Coalescence** and its discussed in details under aggregation pipelines optimizations (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#match-match-coalescence). 
let me explain more with an example.

lets say we have x = [1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55];  and we want to filter that in our aggregates. case one.
I have made a comparison of first greater than and then less than for a reason.

```
$project:
 {
  $and: [ { $gt: [ "$qty", 25 ] },{ $lt: [ "$qty", 5 ] }]
 }
```

> we should get a result of  8,13,21

Next lets try this one

$project:

```
$and:
[
 {
  $and:[{ $gt: [ "$qty", 25 ] }],                                                                                          
  $and:[{ $lt: [ "$qty", 5 ] }],                                                                                                                            
 }
]
```

> we should get a result of  8,13,21 the reason being its gone do this in one go

Last Example

```
$and:
[
  {
    $and:[{ $gt: [ "$qty", 25 ] }],    
  },
  {                                                                                       
    $and:[{ $lt: [ "$qty", 5 ] }],                                                                                                                              
  }
]
```

> we should get [] or empty as a result.

The reason we will get an empty list as a result is the fact that we will be running the above query in two stages. The First Stage will filter our value **x** for numbers greater than 25 and it will return a new list. The next stage then will go on to filter the results of our first stage for numbers less than 5 which will be empty since the result set only contains numbers greater than 25.

So the lesson here is if you are gone nest portions of your query inside $and, $or be advised that each brace is treated as a separate stage and the following stages act upon the result from the previous stage.